# Why is explicit waits flaky?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I have my code below:

```
IWebElement elem = null;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverContext.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));               
elem = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[contains(string(@id),'confirm')]/div/div[2]/a[1]")));
elem.Click();
```

I tried to run and it would give me below exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (437, 505). Other element would receive the click: <td style="width: 60%; padding-left: 5px; text-align: left;">...</td>
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
```

Now I tried to use the implicitly waits:

```
DriverContext.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
elem = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[contains(string(@id),'confirm')]/div/div[2]/a[1]")));
elem.Click();
```

Same exception error is displayed. But then I used Thread.Sleep() instead of implicitly waits- which I know is a bad practice, it miraculously worked. Am I on the right path?

Comment: When you use ImplicitlyWait, does it fail on the `DriverContext.Driver.FindElement` line or on the `wait.Until` line?

Comment: @user246 sorry I updated the implicitly waits part, it fails on the wait.Until line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is misleading. The expectation `ElementToBeClickable` doesn't really check that the element is clickable. It checks that the element **is displayed** and **not disabled**.

On the other hand, the click also checks that the element on top at the coordinates of the click is your element or a descendant. This additional test ensures that the element **is really visible from a user perspective**.
Unfortunately, there's no built-in condition to test it.

If in your case you are facing a transition effect, then try to wait for a minimum height/width:

```java
WebElement elem = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.XPath(...)));
wait.until((WebDriver drv) -> elem.getSize().getHeight() > 15 ? element : null)
    .click();
```

Or try to click your element until it succeeds :

```java
wait.until((WebDriver drv) -> {
    try {
        elem.click();
        return true;
    } catch (WebDriverException ex) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable.`  See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2313 for details.

As I understand it, if you use `ImplicitlyWait`, `wait.Until` will keep trying the specified predicate until the condition is true or the timeout expires.  As the above bug report describes, `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable` ought return false if the specified element is hidden behind another element, but instead it throws an exception.

`Thread.Sleep` works because it waits long enough for your element to appear.

You might try calling `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf`  (inside `waitUntil`) first to ensure the element is visible before calling `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable.`